# failed to open stream: No such file or directory with "alphard-code/sitemap" extension

Tags: php, yii

I am new to php, Yii and working on trackstar example given in

"agile-web-application-development-with-yii-1-1-and-php5.9781847199584.52717"

I am trying to use following sitemap extension for yii

https://github.com/alphard-code/sitemap

Followed all steps to implement sitemap extension mentioned in above link but getting following warning, googled error but can't resolve it please help.

PHP warning

include(yiiExtensions/sitemap/SitemapComponent.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(421)

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the file in config/main.php as shown below

Place the extension in protected/extension folder and place the code shown below in main.php file

```
'import'=>array(
    'ext.yiiExtensions.sitemap.SitemapComponent',
),
```

Comment: extension was already placed in protected/extension folder. Added import in main.php but still same problem.

Comment: Yii::import("application.protected.extensions.yiiExtensions.sitemap.SitemapComponent"); try using this

Comment: where to add Yii::import() call, i mean which file?

Comment: You can add it to the view or the controller file which is calling the view that uses this extension like <? Yii::import() ?>

Comment: added it in view file but no luck

Comment: yes same warning "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Comment: Check the folder structure and correct path try using using different folder names

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong file path. In yii "Application." gives access up to protected folder, further we can add path like in my case it was

Application.extension.sitemap.SitemapComponent

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507